# unable to render a bullet list in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

i am not being able to render a bulleted list through xml/xsl transformation. I want the output to be a list with round bullet points.

here is the xml file -

```
<bulletList name="list">
        <item>&#8226; Item1</item>
        <item>&#8226; Item2</item>
        <item>&#8226; Item3</item>
        <item>&#8226; Item4</item>
        <item>&#8226; Item5</item>
</bulletList>
```

here is the corresponding XSL -

```
<div class="sansIcon">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="content[@name='con1']" mode="impl_expandContent"/>

            <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="bulletList[@name='list']" mode="impl_expandContent">
                <xsl:for-each select="item">
                    <li><xsl:value-of /></li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:apply-templates>  
            </ul>

       </div>
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it currently output?

Comment: @SimeonVisser - Probably nothing since `xsl:for-each` is not allowed as a child of `xsl:apply-templates` and there is no `@select` in the `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: it displays the bulleted items in a single row.


• Item1 • Item2 • Item3 • Item4 • Item5

Comment: and the bullets come as square bullets, i want round bullets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here change `<xsl:value-of />` to `<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>`

Do this way, rather than using apply-templates for bulletList

```
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="bulletList[@name='list']/item">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

### EDIT:

For this type of XML,

```
<item>Item1 - Description1</item>
<item>Item2 - Description2</item>
```

To make Item1, Item2, .... to be bold. Use `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`

```
<li>
    <xsl:variable name="itemText" select="substring-before(text(), '-')"/>
    <b><xsl:value-of select="$itemText"/></b><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(), $itemText)"/>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Siva! this worked perfectly fine! I have one small modification in the requirement. the xml i have is actually, 

<item>Item1 - Description1</item>
<item>Item2 - Description2</item>

Now, I want the texts Item1, Item2 to come in bold, the rest as normal. How can I do that? Please help

Comment: i used the <strong> tag in the following manner - 

<item><strong>Item1</strong> Description</item>

This doesn't seem to work.